# Java only get Exception name without StackTrace

Tags: java, string, exception, stack-trace

how can I get the exception name without getting the stack trace?

I am using `exception.toString()` to convert the thrown exception into a string, but I only want the exception name like`NullPointerException` and not the entire stack trace.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
exception.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

[Class#getSimpleName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName())

NOTE: this will not work in case if your exception is an anonymous class (although I have personally never seen an anonymous exception in any production code)

Comment: won't work with some jar libraries too. will throw class not found exception.